# Ribbon buttons greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

From Files 
New Document/Upload Document/New Folder/Edit Document/Library Setting have been greyed out for all web application/ sites.
I have admin rights with Full Control and checked with all browsers (run as administrator)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: take a look into Central Administration, any errors?

Comment: The database or site collection could be make read only? It's for all lists not only document libraries right?

Comment: Giwny there are errors in Central Admin also. For example at "View these issues" when i click on an issue "Run Now", "Reanalyze Now" etc are greyed out.

Comment: @Andreas my account has dbo rights I think is something with C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates.ascx.  Cause i have some errors there, but, i dont want to try to fix them. Is there any way to restore a previous version?

Comment: If you haven't changed those files manually (which you shouldn't have) than that shouldn't be the issue.

Are all actions greyed out in every list? Or is it only document libraries?

Comment: When i check a document/file View properties after everything is greyed out. For Survey list there is no Respond to this survey/Actions/Settings no Views menu.

Comment: HTML Incompatibility detected. This page contains code that is incompatible with the selected schema.

Comment: i have disabled the updates from server, cause when i was doing them server turned off. There are 70 updates. Do you think that an update could resolve the issue?